# INVALID CREDENTIALS error when trying to update Laravel/Nova via Composer to latest release

Tags: json, laravel, composer-php, updates, laravel-nova

I have been trying for two days now to update Nova

After getting the composer.json file correct to where the update process seems to be functioning, correctly I get an authentication error.

> Package operations: 1 install, 0 updates, 0 removals
>
> Installing laravel/nova (v2.0.11):  Downloading (connecting...)    Failed to download laravel/nova from dist: Invalid credentials for
>   'https://nova.laravel.com/dist/laravel/nova/laravel-nova-blahblahblah-zip-blah.zip', aborting.

I am using the email and password I use to successfully login to the nova.laravel.com.  I have retested and verified it is correct.

Initially the composer update process interactively asked for my username and password during update - this also returned invalid credentials.

The next thing I tried was adding these credentials into my auth.json file

```
{
    "http-basic": {
        "nova.laravel.com": {
            "username": "myname@mydomain.com",
            "password": "mypassword"
        }
    },
    "github-oauth": {
        "github.com": "mykey"
    }
}
```

Now It no longer asks for my credentials but returns Invalid credentials for 'https://nova.laravel.com/....

I also tried using my license key in place of the password.

Initially I was trying to update from `2.05` to `2.1.0` and wondered if I had to stay below `2.1.0` with my licence key so then I tried updating to `2.0.11` - but had the same issue.

Would much appreciate some help getting out of this Laravel Nova update hell.

My `composer.json` file

```
 "name": "laravel/laravel",
    "description": "The Laravel Framework.",
    "keywords": [
        "framework",
        "laravel"
    ],
    "license": "MIT",
    "type": "project",
    "require": {
        "php": "^7.1.3",
        "ext-json": "*",
        "fideloper/proxy": "^4.0",
        "intervention/image": "^2.4",
        "laravel/cashier": "^9.3",
        "laravel/framework": "5.8.*",
        "laravel/nexmo-notification-channel": "^2.0",
        "laravel/nova": "~2.0",
        "laravel/tinker": "^1.0",
        "laravelcollective/html": "^5.5",
        "pusher/pusher-php-server": "~4.0",
        "stechstudio/laravel-php-cs-fixer": "^1.2",
        "willvincent/laravel-rateable": "^1.07"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "barryvdh/laravel-debugbar": "^3.2",
        "filp/whoops": "^2.0",
        "fzaninotto/faker": "^1.4",
        "mockery/mockery": "^1.0",
        "nunomaduro/collision": "^3.0",
        "phpunit/phpunit": "^7.5",
        "beyondcode/laravel-dump-server": "^1.0"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "classmap": [
            "database/seeds",
            "database/factories"
        ],
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "app/"
        }
    },
    "autoload-dev": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Tests\\": "tests/"
        }
    },
    "extra": {
        "laravel": {
            "dont-discover": []
        }
    },
    "scripts": {
        "post-root-package-install": [
            "@php -r \"file_exists('.env') || copy('.env.example', '.env');\""
        ],
        "post-create-project-cmd": [
            "@php artisan key:generate"
        ],
        "post-autoload-dump": [
            "Illuminate\\Foundation\\ComposerScripts::postAutoloadDump",
            "@php artisan package:discover"
        ],
        "post-update-cmd": [
            "@php artisan nova:publish"
        ]
    },
    "repositories": [
        {
            "type": "composer",
            "url": "https://nova.laravel.com"
        }
    ],
    "config": {
        "preferred-install": "dist",
        "sort-packages": true,
        "optimize-autoloader": true
    },
    "minimum-stability": "dev",
    "prefer-stable": true
}
```

Comment: Did you managed to solve it?

Comment: I have the same issue how did you solve that?

Comment: Actually what I've understood you need to buy a license first :) Once the I've purchased Nova license I've got everything setup, and the composer install worked fine

Comment: Solved I had Laravel reissue the license and after a reinstall it worked

Answer (score 2):

I have similar working setup than yours, I'll paste the relevant parts so you can review it by character if you need it.

#### {base_path}/composer.json

```
{
    "name": "laravel/laravel",
    "description": "The Laravel Framework.",
    "keywords": ["framework", "laravel"],
    "license": "MIT",
    "type": "project",
    "require": {

        // ...

        "laravel/nova": "~2.0",

        // ...

    },

    // ...

    "repositories": [
        {
            "type": "composer",
            "url": "https://nova.laravel.com"
        }
    ],
}
```

#### {base_path}/auth.json

```
{
  "http-basic": {
    "nova.laravel.com": {
      "username": "my@email.com",
      "password": "my-password"
    }
  }
}
```

Keep in mind that the password is case sensitive.

---

### Note

You shouldn't have any trouble with your license, it will cover a major release "series", all the first round of updates have came out under the "orion" series. I think this will last until the release of Laravel 6.

As a workaround, you could also [update your Nova manually](https://nova.laravel.com/docs/2.0/installation.html#updating-nova).

Answer (score 0):

Just for visibility since I ran into the same issue. For some reason my CI/CD broke after 1.5 years.

xarga had the right solution for me. I had to cycle my Nova license. (You can do this at https://nova.laravel.com/licenses)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34583797)